# MySQL cannot INSERT with FK constraint

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I get the following error message when I try to INSERT some data:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`database/UserDetails`, CONSTRAINT `UserDetails_ibfk_6` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`HearAboutID`) REFERENCES `UserDetails` (`HearAboutID`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

The FK relationship looks like this:

[image]

The data I'm trying to enter into `UserDetails.HearAboutID` is present in `UserHearAbout.UserHearAboutID`... so why won't it go? :(

Comment: Can you include the SQL that you're using please? Also double check that you've not created some kind of circular reference with FK between the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error you posted

> FOREIGN KEY (HearAboutID) REFERENCES UserDetails (HearAboutID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

(you actually created a constraint that refers to the same table and same column), 
I guess that your FK constraint definition is wrong (it should be

```
 FOREIGN KEY (HearAboutID) REFERENCES UserHearAbout (UserHearAboutID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: DOH! I can't believe I did that. Schoolboy error! Thanks very much.